CQL schema parser fails on startup when system locale set to tr_TR.UTF-8 with SyntaxException: "no viable alternative at character 'ı'"
I installed Apache Cassandra from this sources list:
deb [signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/apache-cassandra.asc] https://debian.cassandra.apache.org 50x main
Then I started it from systemctl. I know it should automaticly start right? After start I got active (exited). I knew that services like database or web server should be persistend and active (running) I dig down and in /var/log/cassandra/system.log I found the error below:
ERROR [main] 2024-09-25 14:50:58,401 CassandraDaemon.java:900 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setupVirtualKeyspaces(CassandraDaemon.java:575)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:286)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:744)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:878)
Caused by: org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.SyntaxException: Failed parsing CREATE TABLE: [CREATE TABLE streaming (  id timeuuid,
  follower boolean,
  operation text, 
  peers frozen<list<text>>,
  status text,
  progress_percentage float,
  last_updated_at timestamp,
  duration_millis bigint,
  failure_cause text,
  success_message text,

  bytes_to_receive bigint, 
  bytes_received bigint, 
  bytes_to_send bigint, 
  bytes_sent bigint, 
  files_to_receive bigint, 
  files_received bigint, 
  files_to_send bigint, 
  files_sent bigint, 

  status_ınıt_timestamp timestamp,
  status_start_timestamp timestamp,
  status_success_timestamp timestamp,
  status_faılure_timestamp timestamp,

PRIMARY KEY ((id)))] reason: SyntaxException line 21:9 no viable alternative at character 'ı'
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.CQLFragmentParser.parseAny(CQLFragmentParser.java:48)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.statements.schema.CreateTableStatement.parse(CreateTableStatement.java:465)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.virtual.StreamingVirtualTable.<init>(StreamingVirtualTable.java:37)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.virtual.SystemViewsKeyspace.<init>(SystemViewsKeyspace.java:47)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.virtual.SystemViewsKeyspace.<clinit>(SystemViewsKeyspace.java:26)
    ... 4 common frames omitted

So, I changed my system language, re-created and deleted locales (switched from tr_TR.UTF-8 to en_US.UTF-8), and changed it from GNOME Settings too.
I use Ubuntu 24.02. In this error you see 'ı' (a Turkish character, i but without dot) used and Java basically couldn't find an alternative for 'ı' but the question is I just installed Cassandra. I didn't created this table. This is probably for Cassandra and created automaticly by Cassandra (I didn't used Cassandra this was about to be my first time but as you can see I got error).
What I should do now? I turned my system language to en_US.UTF-8 but error didn't resolved. Is this a bug?
Also, I tried other stable version 41x, same result. I completly removed /var/lib/cassandra and /var/log cassandra before install too.
EDIT: I think I found and it is probably a bug.
In StreamingVirtualTable.java file, stateCoulmns() funciton contains a toLowerCase().
sb.append(" status_").append(state.name().toLowerCase()).append("_timestamp timestamp,\n");

In my language lowercase "I" is equals "ı". So can we fix with .toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH)?

Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to DBA Stack Exchange. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

That's a very interesting error that I've never seen before. I don't think the system language should matter but we need to investigate further.
It would be fantastic if you would please log a ticket on the project Jira with detailed instructions on how to replicate the problem. Cheers!

[UPDATE] Noting here for posterity -- issue was logged by OP as CASSANDRA-19953. 

I found error and I will do a pull request. I am adding all the toLowerCase() functions "Locale.US". Is this would great?

@Ataİlhan that would be awesome!
